# Typescript React handleChange() or handleSubmit() Form not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm working on my first typescript react project so I'm a beginner trying to go through the loops. I have a form with 3 different select fields. For now what I'm trying to do is when you submit the form for it to display the values you selected.

With my code below if I were to change a select option lets say from yes to no, in my console for that `handleChange` it will display null for that event. Also, when I submit the form for any field in which I have changed the select value it will display undefined in the alert.

I did notice that whenever I select a value in the drop down that the console reloads. So I'm not to sure if that's what is causing it to display a null.

I'm looking for the best way to store the selection that the user selected:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './TeacherSelector.module.scss';
import { ITeacherSelectorProps } from './ITeacherSelectorProps';


export default class TeacherSelector extends React.Component<ITeacherSelectorProps, {tenure: string, grade: string, location: string}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tenure: 'yes',
            grade: 'first',
            location: 'new-york',
        };

        this.handleChangeTenure = this.handleChangeTenure.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeGrade = this.handleChangeGrade.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeLocation = this.handleChangeLocation.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this);            

    }

    handleChangeTenure(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.setState({tenure: event.target.tenure});
    }

    handleChangeGrade(event) {
        console.log(event);
        this.setState({grade: event.target.grade});
    }

    handleChangeLocation(event) {
        this.setState({location: event.target.location});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Tenure: ' + this.state.tenure + 'Grade: ' + this.state.grade + 'Location: ' + this.state.location);
    }


    public render(): React.ReactElement<ITeacherSelectorProps> {

        return (
            <div className={ styles.TeacherSelector }>
                <div className={ styles.container }>
                    <div className={ styles.row }>
                        <div className={ styles.column }>

                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <label>
                                    Tenure (YES/NO):
                                    <select name="tenure" value={this.state.tenure} onChange={(Val: any) => this.handleChangeTenure(Val)}>
                                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="no">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>

                                <label>
                                    Teaching Grade Level
                                    <select  name="grade" value={this.state.grade} onChange={this.handleChangeGrade}>
                                        <option value="first">first</option>
                                        <option value="second">second</option>
                                        <option value="third">third</option>
                                        <option value="fourth">fourth</option>                                        
                                    </select>
                                </label>

                                <label>
                                    Location
                                    <select name="location" value={this.state.location} onChange={this.handleChangeLocation}>
                                        <option value="new-york">New York</option>
                                        <option value="queens">Queens</option>
                                        <option value="new-jersey">New Jersey</option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>                                

                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            </form>                         

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to access the `value` property on `event.target` instead of `grade`, `location` or `tenure`, as these do not exist.

```
handleChangeTenure(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({tenure: event.target.value}); // not .tenure
}
// repeat for other handle.. events
```

I would also recommend assigning that event value to a variable before using `setState` on it. `this.setState` happens asynchronously so by the time it fires, the synthetic `event` is usually released which can cause issues. You can either assign `value` to another value (my recommendation) or you can call `event.persist()` to keep your event around until you don't need it anymore, though this comes with its own caveats.
More reading here: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

```
handleChangeTenure(event) {
    // temp variable first = no more chrome console complaining about synthetic events
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({tenure: value });
}
```

Here's a code sandbox link demonstrating the changes working:

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-xi6hz)

(Typescript has been stripped out for this code sandbox but the important parts are easily transplantable)